# Google Maps API v3 How can this callback function work?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

So here is my problem.
The callback function is not called. And I'dont know why. Or even how this works.
How can I call a function with parameters and not put the parameters on the call?

Here's the code

```
    var addr = new Array(5);
    addr[0] = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.352646,-53.384881);
    addr[1] = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.344648,-53.395009);
    addr[2] = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.365562,-53.388859);
    addr[3] = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.366241,-53.401655);
    addr[4] = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.360467,-53.397476);


    var a = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.352901,-53.402745);
    var menorDistancia;
    var destinoFinal;
    function callback(response, status) {
        alert("CHEGOU AQUI")
      if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        var element = results[j];
        var distance = element.distance.text;
        var duration = element.duration.text;
        var from = origins[i];
        var to = destinations[j];
        if(distance < menorDistancia || i==0){
            menorDistancia = distance;
            destinoFinal = to;
        }
      }
    }
  }
    }

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [a,a,a,a,a],
            destinations: [addr[0],addr[1],addr[2],addr[3],addr[4]],
        }, callback);
```

Comment: your script looks alright to me, is there any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the travelMode:

```
service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
        origins: [a,a,a,a,a],
        destinations: [addr[0],addr[1],addr[2],addr[3],addr[4]],
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    }, callback);
```

per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DistanceMatrixRequest):

> travelMode | TravelMode | Type of routing requested. **Required**

Comment: TravelMode is optional and defaults to DiretionsTravelMode.DRIVING if left out. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

Comment: Hah, just saw your edit but my link still says it's optional with a default value :)

Comment: The documentation is inconsistent.  When it wasn't there the code threw a javascript error that it wasn't defined and it didn't work.  Adding it to the request worked (the callback ran).

Comment: Thank you so very much man.
I didn't even see that. As it was default I thought I could just take it out. But I forgot to take the ',' out too.